# Selecting with multiple conditions in a Single SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, rdbms, ddl

Table name is **Student**

[image]

I need the SQL query which gives names of students who are Math majors with more than 30 credits.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 select *
 from Student 
 where major='Math' and  credits>30;
```

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL

```
select firstName, lastName from Student where major='Math' and  
credit>30;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select * 
from student
where major ='Math' and credit> 30
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Multiple conditions in WHERE Clause :

```
   SELECT firstName, lastName 
   FROM Student 
   WHERE major='Math' AND credit>30;
```

Answer (score 0):

Like others have rightly answered, the query should look like this and nothing more:

```
SELECT firstName, lastName FROM Student WHERE major='Math' AND credits>30;
```

It is worth nothing that, since you are mainly interested in just the full names of the students in the result, being specific on the name column is what is needed in the query and not SELECT ALL. This will greatly improve response time if you are working with a huge database.